# What is the difference between "cosmos", "world", "universe"?

Tags: meaning, differences, nouns

Are these words different in meaning: *cosmos, world, universe*?

Does *world* mean just the Earth and not other planets?

Comment: The answers you receive will be most helpful if you can demonstrate what research you have already done (e.g. dictionary definitions), and provide the context where you have seen conflicting or overlapping uses of these words. Please review the [Help Center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for guidance.

Comment: You should substantiate your questions,I think they deserve approbation (if you do).

Comment: which word we use when we just mean earth?and which one we use when mean all creations and planets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Cosmos, world, universe.

The *universe* is ... well the universe within which everything exists.

The *cosmos* could be considered a more poetic form of synonym for universe: the Greek etymology distinguishes it as a "well-ordered" version of the universe. It's what you see when you look at the universe with starry-eyes.

A *world* gives more of an enclosed sense: a somewhat enclosed plane/sphere of existence. It does not encompass everything like the universe does. In a cosmic sense, it often refers to a planet or a planetoid or occasionally a moon. Though one *could* describe a lifeless planet as a world, for me, *world* also has a slight connotation leaning towards the presence of life.

> Does "world" mean just the earth and not other planets?

"World" can refer to other planets: "other worlds".

"World" also does not need to refer to a planet: "the world of competitive ploughing".

Comment: World can not refer to other planets .

Comment: Yes it can. [14 :  a celestial body (as a planet) -- Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/world). This sense is pretty widely used.

Comment: No world can exist wherever life exists and life exists only on earth , sci-fi movies .....this is why movies are like the part of iceberg which can be seen and book is like the part in water.

Comment: Again, the notion of a world is not restricted to earth. If you don't trust me, trust [Carl Sagan](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KfIaq5ihoeM&list=PLE5ECDA862312A35E#t=49).

Comment: Travellers from something to sun !Awesome anything could happen,as I said sci fi. My previous comment is a disaster...it should've been -: no,world

Comment: Carl was not implying that there was life on Jupiter or Saturn or Uranus by calling them worlds. In any case, I give up. :) The notion of a world is certainly *not* restricted to Earth nor to planets on which there is life. For this I gave two good sources; do with them what you will.

Answer (score 0):

By Wikipedia-:
World is a common name for the whole of human civilization, specifically human experience, history, or the human condition in general, worldwide, i.e. anywhere on Earth or pertaining to anywhere on earth.
Universe is the totality of our existence.
Cosmos is the Universe regarded as a beautifully-arranged system.
By me-:
Earth is the world of human beings , have you ever heard of the phrase " living in your own world " or something like "for these slum children,this wilderness is their world".(answering comment). 
Universe is the aggregate of all aggregates.
Cosmos ....

Comment: For better understanding of the word and  not about the word instead of Wikipedia , sites like this one(Merriam Webster) should be used-:http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/world (it will leave no traces of ambiguity on this word)

Comment: Disambiguation -: emphasis on " about " in previous comment.